# Xamarin.Forms: how to access to the "Reload" method of a WebView from a ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, webview, command, code-behind

I'm working on a **Xamarin.Forms** app that contains a **WebView** allowing users to schedule an appointment:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="{Binding UrlBooking}" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
```

I would like to use use a **ToolbarItem** to reset/reload the **WebView**.

I'm able to achieve this in the **code-behind** with:

```
this.webView.Reload();
```

***But I don't see how to this with a Command in the ViewModel. Is it possible to do this?***

Comment: the VM should raise an event which the view subscribes to.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, and how could I do this?

Comment: there are thousands of existing posts on creating custom events in C#

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you've suggested me. Is it related about behaviours?

Comment: No, just basic C# events.  However, you could also just have your Toolbar item call the WebView Refresh directly without involving the VM.

Comment: Yes sure, it was what I did as a first step.

Comment: If that works why change it?

Comment: Cause I want to manage all the business code in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Command` my `CommandParameter` to achieve it in `ToolbarItem`.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyCusListview.ToolbarItemPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="reload"
                 Command="{Binding ReloadWebview}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference webView}}"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Priority="0" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <WebView Source="https://www.google.com/" x:Name="webView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" ></WebView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
 public partial class ToolbarItemPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ToolbarItemPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new PersonsViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Here is `PersonsViewModel.cs`, add `ICommand`, and achieve it in the `PersonsViewModel`'s construtor.

```
 public ICommand ReloadWebview { protected set; get; }

 public PersonsViewModel()
{
            ReloadWebview = new Command<WebView>((key) =>
            {
                key.Reload();


            });
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: Looking into achieving something similar. Is this not a violation of MVVM principles though? I feel like the ViewModel shouldn't be calling any webview methods like .Reload

Comment: In simple WebView doesnt support for MVVM